# How to send Asynchronous Requests in Java and Collect Responses

Tags: java, asynchronous, rx-java

I have a list of lets say 2000 user ids and i want to send asynchronous requests to the same server passing the id as a parameter to the `WebTarget`.

The System will return JSON which is mapped to class UserReport. It includes a `List<User>` and will be of size 1 (if user was found).

For every result i would like to save the user in a DataBase. Is there a way to make it all Asynchronous? i.e As soon as i get a response send an INSERT to the Database.

My code to send a single request:

```
public UserReport runRequest(String id){
    return this.webTarget.path("some_path")
            .queryParam("id", id)
            .request(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_TYPE)
            .get(new GenericType<UserReport >() {});
}
```

Last question.. Use Observable or Future?

Comment: http://howtodoinjava.com/core-java/multi-threading/how-to-use-blockingqueue-and-threadpoolexecutor-in-java/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved it using `ExecutorService` and `Future`

I post the answer:

```
public List<User> getAllUsers(List<String> ids) {

    List<Future<UserReport>> futures = new ArrayList<>();
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

    int counterU = 0;
    for (String id : ids) {
        Callable<UserReport> task = () -> {
            return runRequest(id);
        };
        futures.add(executor.submit(task));
        LOGGER.info("Added Task {} for UserId {}.", counterH++, id);
    }

    List<User> toReturn = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Future<UserReport> future : futures) {
        try {
            UserReport report = future.get();

            if (report.getUsers() != null) {
                User temp = report.getUsers().get(0);
                LOGGER.info("Got details for User {}.", temp.getId());
                toReturn.add(temp);
                insertUserToDB(temp);
            }

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    executor.shutdown();
    return toReturn;
}
```

Comment: A new executor thread pool is created with each method invocation and using only a single thread. You should have a static executor service on the class level. 
Next - your method reads / sends / returns data synchronously, so there's no advantage to use async communication

Comment: But if i need threads only when getAllUsers(List<String> ids)  is called? I tried it this way and it seems that the requests are asynchronous. (first i tried with 100 threads and i crushed the server :D, doing it with 10-20 the server responded ok)

Comment: You are right, the requests are asynchronous, only storing the results is serialized, but now I see what you wanted to achieve :) I just didn't like creating a new thread pool for each call. Since you shut it down it's maybe ok..

Answer (score 0):

First, `List<User>` with size 0 or 1 can change to `Optional<User>`.

You can use `flatMap` to scheduler async tasks. Here is my code.

```
public class Q43912265 {

  static Random random = new Random();

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Observable.range(1, 1000)
        .map(String::valueOf)
        .flatMap(id ->
            Observable.just(id)
                .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .map(Q43912265::runRequest))
        .filter(ur -> ur.getUser().isPresent())
        .doOnNext(Q43912265::insert)
        .subscribe();
  }

  @SneakyThrows(InterruptedException.class)
  static UserReport runRequest(String id) {
    System.out.printf("request %s on %s\n", id, Thread.currentThread());
    Thread.sleep(random.nextInt(1000));
    System.out.printf("done %s on %s\n", id, Thread.currentThread());
    return new UserReport(id, Optional.ofNullable(random.nextDouble() > 0.7 ? null : new User(random.nextInt())));
  }

  static void insert(UserReport ur) {
    System.err.printf("insert %s on %s\n", ur, Thread.currentThread());
  }
}

@Value
class UserReport {
  String id;
  Optional<User> user;
}

@Value
class User {
  int id;
}
```

Note that if you run code above directly, it will terminate before all tasks done. To make it blocking.

And in this case, you can change schedulers with limited thread or `io` scheduler will create about 1000 thread.

Comment: Those annotations are from "lombok". You can ignore them and give the class constructor and `toString`.